# How To Create Text File From Excel Values

Tags: vba, excel

Im currently working on a tool that will enable me to create my specific profile for entries present in my Excel File.

Assuming that I have these values:
Male:     [image]

And I want to generate a text file like this one below. There must be separate filename for both female and male and one file per row only.

[image]

I currently have this code below:

```
Sub toFile()

    Dim FilePath As String, CellData As String, LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Filenum As Integer

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".xpd"
        Filenum = FreeFile

        Open FilePath For Output As Filenum
        CellData = ""

        For j = 2 To LastCol
        CellData = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
        Write #Filenum, CellData

        Next j

        Close #Filenum

    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Sample Output of this code:

[image]

How can I achieve my expected output mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final code which will create two files and won't write values where cells are blank:

```
Sub toFile()

    Dim FilePath As String, CellData As String, LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Filenum As Integer

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".TXT"
        Filenum = FreeFile

        Open FilePath For Output As Filenum
        CellData = ""

        For j = 2 To LastCol
            If Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value) <> "" Then
                CellData = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, j).Value) & ": " & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
                Write #Filenum, CellData
            End If
        Next j

        Close #Filenum

    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! :) However, what if I want a customized title for both male and female text file? Example. I want to add "His First Name" and "Her First Name"?

Comment: So file name would be "His First Name.txt"? I am bit confused.

Comment: No, I just want to have different display of File Contents for Male and Female text file.

Comment: Basically, I just want to assign every cell values in a variable so I can use it anytime and anywhere. How can I able to to that on this code?

Comment: The code that I gave you will display different content in different file for Male and Female. And to assign cell values to variable, create different variable and assign values to it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code
Change  the code

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
```

and

```
celldata = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, j)) & ": " & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
```